# Android Data Persistence

Tags: android, orm, persistence

I have to port an iOS app to Android. The iOS App uses Core Data for persistence and makes somewhat heavy use of many-to-many relationships, entity inheritance and abstract entities. I've been researching for a valid replacement API for Android, most popular options like ORMLite don't seem to have direct support for these features.

Does anybody have experience in how to go on about this? I'm pretty much in the dark.

Comment: Android does not have a built-in object-persistence framework. If you don't want to use SQLite manually you have to use ORMLite, 
greenDAO, ..

Comment: Highly recommend using ORMLite, very easy to use. Simplifies code a ton

Comment: As I already mentioned, these libraries don't have good support for many to many relationships and entity inheritance. At least not in the way I know it from Core Data.

Answer (score 0):

Preferred choice is [ContentProvider](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) as it allows to use [CursorLoaders](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/CursorLoader.html) which do their job on separate threads, then report results to main. This way UI stays always responsive.